# Touch and Drag with Flash Builder

Tags: flash, touch, pivot, drag, builder

I'm working on a not very complex project in Flash Builder that requires a touch and drag events using some images.

Everything is working as aspected except a issue i can't get fixed:
When dragging the objects the image snaps to the upper left corner of the image. I think this is because it's pivot point is there, i tried to change it using a Matrix but i didnt fix this issue. I want the image to be drag by its center.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you using the startDrag() and stopDrag() methods? If so, they normally would take care of problems like the above for you. startDrag() also have a related lockCenter parameter you can try http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag()

Comment: Hi,
i'm not using starDrag at the moment i'm 
img1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin); 
e.target.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID, false, bg.getRect(this));
wich locked to the point where the user first clicked the sprite

this is not my actual code :)
ty for the reply

Comment: OK, startTouchDrag() and stopTouchDrag() are probably the right choice, as they correspond to startDrag() and stopDrag() but for touch, and also have the lockCenter parameter.

Comment: Isn't the false in the next line of code setting it to be lockCenter?
e.target.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID, false, bg.getRect(this));

Comment: No, it's the other way around, I believe. lockCenter is false by default, and if you want to turn it on, you would instead send true. So e.target.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID, true, bg.getRect(this));

Comment: Well i'm at the job right now so i can't try it but ill as soon as possivel :)
Ty for the help